# Generate DER format public key from PEM format certificate and PEM format public key

Tags: openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I made the following steps before getting struck

1) I got the certificate of a server using

```
 s_client -connect hostname.org:443 -showcerts
```

The certificates looks good

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIICTCCBvGgAwIBAgIQA8mdxgOCgSdtPdwJY/c3FzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBk
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJOTDEWMBQGA1UECBMNTm9vcmQtSG9sbGFuZDESMBAGA1UEBxMJ
and so on
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

2) I saved it as myCert.pem file.(I am not sure if i should have saved it as .cer file )

3) I extracted the public key in PEM format, form the above saved certificate file, using

```
openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in myCert.pem > pubkey.pem
```

The PEM format public key looks good too

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

**Now I am trying to decode this PEM format public key to der format. How can i do it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PEM encoded file is the header, the footer, and base64-encoded contents (which, for certs and keys and stuff, is BER/DER encoded data).

When OpenSSL writes data it uses the constraints from DER (as far as I've seen), so for OpenSSL-written data you just need to base64-decode the contents.  `openssl base64 -d` will do that (ignoring the PEM header/footer)

```
openssl base64 -d -in pubkey.key -out pubkey.der
```

If you were worried that the PEM contents were legal BER but not legal DER (for example, that it used indefinite-length constructed values), you could ask OpenSSL to read and write it.

```
openssl rsa -pubin -in pubkey.key -outform der -out pubkey.der
```

or, programmatically

```
FILE* fp = fopen("pubkey.key", "r");
EVP_PKEY* pkey = PEM_read_PUBKEY(fp, NULL, NULL, NULL);
fclose(fp);
fp = fopen("pubkey.der", "wb");
i2d_PUBKEY_fp(fp, pkey);
fclose(fp);
EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
```

Optionally with error checking.

Comment: when using the above two commands, a file is created. when i try to open this file, i get "This file is invalid to use as the following: Security certificate". When i open it in notepad++, i see only gibbrish like 0‚"0
 *†H†÷
 ‚ 0‚
 How can i know that a valid public key in DER format is created?

Comment: @overflow DER is a binary format, not a text format.  And it's a key, not a certificate. You can throw it at a tool like https://lapo.it/asn1js/, or you can ask another tool or library to read it and see if it can.  At the end of the day, you need the data for something, and it either works or it doesn't (and then when it doesn't a more specific question might be more answerable).

Comment: i wanted to see if its something that's, lets say, 'valid'. Now that the tool you shared can read it, i am satisfied. Thanks for the help.